# How to stop useEffect from loading my modal multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a function based React view which has a modal that loads based on the presence of an item in the local storage:

```
function myView() {
...

        function HelpModal() {

            const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
            
            useEffect(()=>{
              let pop_status = localStorage.getItem('this-page-modal');
              if(!pop_status){
                  setShow(true);
              }
            },[])
            if(!setShow) return null;
            
            
          
            const handleClose = () => {
                localStorage.setItem('this-page-modal', '1');
                setShow(false);
            };
            const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
            
          
            return (
              <>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                 Button text
                </Button>
          
                <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                  <Modal.Body>
                      <p>Hey! This is a modal.</p>
                   </Modal.Body>
                  <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                      Close
                    </Button>
                  </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
              </>
            );
          }

return (
<div>

  <Container style={{marginTop: "1em"}}>
                <Row>
                    <Col><h1>My View</h1></Col>
                    <Col><span style={{float: "right"}}> <HelpModal /></span></Col>
                </Row>
 </Container>

</div>
);

}
```

**The problem:** When I load the page, the modal flickers and loads 2 or 3 times.

How do I make it load only once? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: That `useEffect` is not loading multiple times, you are using `[]` as the second argument, that means it is only going to be called when constructed, so someone is calling your modal multiple times, but your `useEffect` is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, you can use `useLayoutEffect` to make the update occur quicker, near instantaneously, instead of a bit after a repaint with `useEffect`.

Also, the `if(!setShow) return null;` line is completely superfluous because the `useState` setter function will always be a function, which is truthy.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const pop_status = localStorage.getItem('this-page-modal');
    if (!pop_status) {
        setShow(true);
    }
}, []);
```

But since the function inside the effect is completely synchronous, it'd make more sense to use the storage value as the initial value for the `show` state, instead of calling the state setter; you an remove the effect entirely.

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(!localStorage.getItem('this-page-modal'));
const handleClose = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('this-page-modal', '1');
    setShow(false);
};
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
return (
    // ...
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the main problem either.

Comment: There is no other code in your question that could produce the problem you describe. If that doesn't solve the issue, your question is lacking a [MCVE] - please edit enough code into the question for the problem to be reproducible, ideally in a live Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup could be causing re-renders based upon code not represented here so it's difficult to diagnose the exact issue. One thing to try might be to put a `console.log` statement in various function scopes to see how many times it's being re-rendered on load. Aside from that, (and concurring with previous answer) I think you might be able to simplify your code down a bit and get the same result by having the conditional render be straight from localStorage. Maybe something like:

```
function HelpModal() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(localStorage.getItem("this-page-modal"));

  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
    localStorage.setItem("this-page-modal", false);
  };

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(true);
    localStorage.setItem("this-page-modal", true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Button text
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <p>Hey! This is a modal.</p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

function myView() {
  return (
    <>
      <HelpModal />
    </>
  );
}
```